# PDFBox search for text on specific page in new PDF

Tags: java, pdfbox, boxable

I'm searching a way to check my new PDF for a specific `String` on every page.
The idea is to go on every page and if project name is missing from the page to add it (before saving the pdf -  `doc.save(new FileOutputStream(new File(pathToFile)));`

I already tried:

`document.save(new FileOutputStream(new File(pathToFile)));`

`PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(pathToFile));`

```
 for (int i = 1; i < document.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            PDFTextStripper reader = new PDFTextStripper();
            reader.setStartPage(i);
            reader.setEndPage(i);
            String pageText = reader.getText(document);
            System.out.println(pageText);
        }
```

the result is : `Hello World` which is ok.

but this is working only if document is already saved and then load it again.

In my case when the document is not saved yet:

```
 for (int i = 1; i < document.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                PDFTextStripper reader = new PDFTextStripper();
                reader.setStartPage(i);
                reader.setEndPage(i);
                String pageText = reader.getText(document);
                System.out.println(pageText);
            }
```

the result is `empty String`

Comment: As @KJ says, parts of the pdf required for text extraction are not finished before asking the document. The optimal solution would be for you to keep track of whether or not the *project name* is on each page while *creating* the document pages. Alternatively, you Indeed have to store and load again.

Comment: I'm using boxable library to create a tables. On the first page i'm adding all project info and when the table is bigger than one page is auto creating second page and i should add only project name there. Maybe i will try different approache. I'll try to calculate pages automatically created and add  the project name only on them.

Comment: You could save and reload to get your project working. But this is not an elegant development style. Does boxable tell you whether it created an extra page? Or can you detect it by calling `PDDocument.getNumberOfPages()` before and after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviasly there is no way to find text before saving the document so I started a new approach.

```
oldPagesCount = document.getNumberOfPages();
addTableInformation(List<String> informationToAdd);
if (oldPagesCount < document.getNumberOfPages()) {
        // we have auto generated pages and we should add projec name-number
        for (int i = oldPagesCount; i < document.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        page = document.getPage(i);
        }
        addProjectInfo(project);
    }
  }
```

In this case if table info is moved to multiple pages the code is going on every newly added page and adding project information. Hope that this will help to everybody that need to do something like this.